# Database Issue in Spring MVC- HIbernate example

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

When I run the [example](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html)

on my system with **mvn tomcat:run** command,

Data in mysql tables get's deleted.

So, I had to insert data every time I restart the application.

Comment: Do you want me to post the code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you followed the tutorial from the linked page exactly, the reason the MySQL data is being removed each time the application starts can be found in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Specifically, it's these lines:

```
<!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
      Existing data will be deleted! -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

I don't remember what the other values are off the top of my head, but I believe `validate` will only check that your schema is correct but not change anything. `update` may also work.